# apt-get upgrade fails with `Permission denied`

Tags: installation, apt, gtk, dpkg

I have recently installed 12.04 and all seemed to be well, until today when I got a series of errors when trying to run `apt-get upgrade`:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade 

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  visual-regexp
The following packages will be upgraded:
  dkms firefox firefox-globalmenu firefox-gnome-support 
  firefox-locale-en gnome-games-data gnome-sudoku gnomine
  google-chrome-stable libglu1-mesa libglu1-mesa:i386 libmysqlclient18:i386 
  mahjongg mysql-common tk8.5 vino
16 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
11 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/67.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 2,890 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? 
(Reading database ... 
dpkg: warning: files list file for package `tk8.5' missing, assuming package has no     files currently installed.
(Reading database ... 235237 files and directories currently installed.)
    Removing visual-regexp ...
dpkg (subprocess): unable to execute installed post-removal script (/var/lib/dpkg/info/visual-regexp.postrm): Permission denied
dpkg: error processing visual-regexp (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
     visual-regexp
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

It all seems to have started with this infamous error:

```
dpkg: warning: files list file for package `tk8.5' missing, 
assuming package has no files currently installed.
```

which was probably originated by my installing `visual-regexp` - which I'm now unable to remove.

I've tried several fixes, including:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get --fix-missing upgrade
```

and others, trying to follow [this answer](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1820060), but to no avail.

Also, I'm not quite clear what the problem may be with the `permission`, as I'm obviously running apt-get as `sudo`:

```
$ ll /var/lib/dpkg/info/visual-regexp.postrm
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 160 Jun 24  2011 /var/lib/dpkg/info/visual-regexp.postrm
```

Also, note the `11 not fully installed or removed.` which was due to previous failures in `apt-get upgrade`: is there any way to recover from this?

Thanks in advance,
Marco.

Comment: So, it suddenly dawned on me that the permission denied thing may be related to the `noexec` option in /etc/fstab (I'm mounting `/var` on a different disk than `/`).

Turns out I'd used the following mount option:

    UUID=b5ae50cf-58e6-46f8-8313-6c1492dcc8ad /var  ext4  defaults,users  0 0

and, while `defaults` implies `exec`, `users` instead implies `noexec` - as the latter is last, it will override the previous one.

Changed it to `defaults` only and all is now ponies and sunshine with `apt-get`.

Posting my own answer in case it helps anyone else out there.

Comment: btw - sorry about formatting, but there's this completely idiotic thing about 'reputation' points that only allows me to post a comment.

Comment: you can always edit your own question.

Comment: ... and you can **answer** your own question!

Comment: duh! about _editing_ my own question (done now, thanks!) -- but, no, you can't _answer_ your own for 8 hours, apparently, if you don't have enough reputation points

Answer (score 3):

OP posted:

So, it suddenly dawned on me that the permission denied thing may be related to the *noexec* option in `/etc/fstab` (I'm mounting `/var` on a different disk than `/`).

Turns out I'd used the following mount option:

```
UUID=b5ae50cf-58e6-46f8-8313-6c1492dcc8ad /var ext4 defaults,users 0 0
```

and, while `defaults` implies `exec`, `users` instead implies `noexec` - as the latter is last, it will override the previous one.

Changed it to `defaults` **only** and all is now ponies and sunshine with apt-get. Leaving it here in case it helps anyone else out there.